# efficient way of padding an array

Tags: python, padding

I was wondering if there is an efficient method to pad an array in python, without using `numpy.pad()`

I know a way that uses nested for loops, but I wanted to know if there's a faster method?

Input:

```
row padding on top- 2
column padding from left - 1
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Output

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 1 2 3
0 4 5 6
0 7 8 9
```

what I've done

```
y = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

topPadding = 2
leftPadding = 1
noOfRows = len(y)+topPadding
noOfCols = len(y)+leftPadding

x = [[0 for i in range(noOfCols)] for j in range(noOfRows)]

for i in range(topPadding,noOfRows):
    for j in range(leftPadding,noOfCols):
        x[i][j] = y[i-topPadding][j-leftPadding]
    print()
        
print(x)
```

Output

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 4, 5, 6], [0, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: is numpy.pad too slow?

Comment: I am trying to build an algorithm that runs on a platform that doesn't have many resources in terms of storage, so NumPy will be heavy on it, for the same reason I don't want to use any external libraries, so I am trying to build alternatives

Comment: That makes sense. But asking for a "a faster method" is a little open ended when there's nothing to compare to (i.e., what you've tried already)

Comment: what I've tried, creates a whole new array and copies the elements one by one, the time complexity is O(n^2), that's the best I can achieve?

Comment: I'm suggesting you include that code as a runnable example in this question.

Comment: alright, will do

Comment: I assume your input is not a Numpy array so is it a list? Better you provide a minimal reproducible example as @PaulH said.

Comment: yeah, I am on it! thank you =))

Comment: I have added, let me know if what I've edited is fine

Comment: If your main goal is speed an obvious speed up is to not create a matrix of zeroes and then copy over values.  Update your `x = [[0 for i in range(noOfCols)] for j in range(noOfRows)]` line to have logic to check indices and either write a 0 or the desired value from the source matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution which uses the `list` concatenation and repetition operators:

```py
def concat(x, top, left):
    n = len(x[0])
    return [[0]*(n + left - len(row)) + row for row in [[]]*top + x]
```

Here are some very basic timing results using your nested `for` loop solution versus my concatenation solution on a `10000x10000` matrix of random digits:

```
nested: 122.26 s
concat: 5.66 s
```

And the code for the test:

```py
import timeit
from random import randint


def concat(x, top, left):
    n = len(x[0])
    return [[0]*(n + left - len(row)) + row for row in [[]]*top + x]


def nested(x, topPadding, leftPadding):
    noOfRows = len(x)+topPadding
    noOfCols = len(x)+leftPadding

    z = [[0 for i in range(noOfCols)] for j in range(noOfRows)]

    for i in range(topPadding,noOfRows):
        for j in range(leftPadding,noOfCols):
            z[i][j] = x[i-topPadding][j-leftPadding]

    return z


test = [[randint(0, 9) for _ in range(10000)] for _ in range(10000)]

t1 = timeit.timeit(
    "nested(test, 4, 2)",
    number=10,
    globals=globals()
)

t2 = timeit.timeit(
    "concat(test, 4, 2)",
    number=10,
    globals=globals()
)

print(nested(test, 4, 2) == concat(test, 4, 2))
print(f"nested: {t1:.2f} s")
print(f"concat: {t2:.2f} s")
```

Full output:

```
True
nested: 122.26 s
concat: 5.66 s
```

A modified version in which you input the desired height and width:

```py
def concat(x, h, w):
    H = h - len(x)
    return [[0]*(w - len(row)) + row for row in [[]]*H + x]
```

Another version which allows padding to the north, south, east, and west:

```py
def nsew_concat(x, N, S, E, W):
    """Pad x with zeros to the north, south, east, and west."""
    k = len(x[0])
    stack = [[]]*N + x + [[]]*S
    return [([0]*W + [0]*(k - len(row)) + row + [0]*E) for row in stack]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any (non-empty) rectangular matrix, but not for jagged arrays (where each row doesn't have the same length).

```py
def pad_matrix(matrix, element=0, *, left=0, top=0):
    full_width = left + len(matrix[0])
    e = [element]
    return [
        *(e * full_width for i in range(top)),
        *(e * left + row for row in matrix),
    ]
```

Here's a version allowing padding on all four sides:

```py
def pad_matrix(matrix, element=0, *, left=0, top=0, right=0, bottom=0):
    full_width = left + len(matrix[0]) + right
    e = [element]
    return [
        *(e * full_width for i in range(top)),
        *(e * left + row + e * right for row in matrix),
        *(e * full_width for i in range(bottom)),
    ]
```

Usage is like `pad_matrix(matrix, left=1, top=2)`.